# VSTO 2010 Intranet deployment (.Net 4.0)

Tags: excel, vsto, intranet

I m novice in vsto.

I have an excel template published in local intranet. the problem is that some computer can run the template but other cannot. (All users have same roles)

is there any local policis that i have to create or edit to let all user from any computer in local network run this template.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do users get any error?

Comment: Yes
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: La personnalisation n'a pas les autorisations requises pour créer un domaine d'application. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: La fonctionnalité personnalisée dans cette application ne fonctionnera pas car l'administrateur a qualifié file://bspc04/Publish/ExcelTemplate.vsto comme étant non fiable.

Comment: so this is what it translate to The customization does not have the permissions required to create an application domain. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because the administrator has qualified file :/ / bspc04/Publish/ExcelTemplate.vsto as unreliable. Please add this in your question

Answer (score 0):

1>Seems user is directly trying to run file from network location. I would suggest you better create installer, it would be quite easy to do using click once.

2>Try to sign your .vsto from trusted publisher.

3>try this to set up security on shared location using  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w6bd8f1(VS.80).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k64zb6we(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I'm already using click once
(i m working under windows7 and using framework4.0) so i can't use **Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration** and the caspol command didn't change anything.
still some computer can run template without error and others got the error already mentioned above.